# How to retrieve value from json of one array and one int literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing data back to java script through a rest api. The rest API return data in the following below mentioned structure.I am confused what format of json is it and how can i iterate on the array inside and get the int value individually.
The format of my response is like :

```
{"searchOrder":[
  {"location":"10","trackingId":"656"},
  {"location":"34","trackingId":"324"},....],
"count":100}
```

i want searchOrder as array of json to display in table and count to show total row.How can i get them?

Comment: What code did you use to retrieve this data?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, depending on the way you used to get this data you may need to perform `JSON.parse(data)` in order to be able to manipulate them.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the array and extract the values

```
// Turn the JSON into a JS object (maybe in your XHR handler)
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString); // jsonString could be responseText from XHR

var arrayOfTrackingIdValues = data.searchOrder.map(function (value) {
    return value.trackingId;
});
```

Comment: Where `var searchOrder = fulldata.searchOrder;`... (Or has otherwise been set to refer to the array within the object...)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript provide built-in function JSON.parse() to convert the string into a JavaScript object and drive/iterate the each element based on type obj/array

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```